# Characterization of least common multiple

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, duality-theorems, least-common-multiple

There is a nice (duality) characterization of the [greatest common divisor (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of two integers $a$ and $b$ known as the [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity): $gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive integer that can be written as $ax + by$.

Is there a similar characterization of the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of two integers $a$ and $b$ such as "$lcm(a,b)$ is the largest $\ldots$"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bézout's identity and the following relationship between the greatest common divisor and the least common multiple to come up with a characterization of $lcm(a,b)$.
$$gcd(a,b) \times lcm(a,b) = a\times b \quad... \;\;(1)$$
$$lcm(a,b) = \frac{ab}{ax+by}$$

However, I am not aware of any other characterizations.

---

EDIT:

[Added proof of **(1)**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470807/prove-that-gcdm-n-times-mboxlcmm-n-m-times-n)

Comment: So lcm(a,b) is the largest integer of the form ab/(ax+by) for any integers x,y.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the definition of $\gcd(a,b)$, valid in any P.I.D., is that it is a generator of the ideal $(a,b)$. In $\mathbf Z$, there are two generators, but there is a canonical way to choose one: it is to take the positive generator. In $F[X]$ ($F$ a field), we usually choose the *monic* generator.

In other P.I.D.s, there is usually no canonical way, as the g.c.d. is defined  within a unit factor. For instance, in ring of *Gaussian integers* $\mathbf Z[i]$, the units are $\;\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ and there is no specific reason to choose one particular g.c.d.

The dual characterization of the l.c.m. of $a$ and $b$ is that it is a generator of the ideal $\;(a)\cap (b)$.  In $\mathbf Z$, we likewise choose the positive generator.